# Android changes are not available in Google Play after creating a new release

Tags: flutter, google-play

I have an issue with an app that is live on Google Play.

I made some changes to the app and created a new release but I never got an update on Google Play and the app version just incremented to the latest version from Google Play Console, but the changes were only available after reinstalling the app.

Does anybody know why this is happening or how it can be fixed?

This is a Flutter app.